# python find specific pattern at end of string

Tags: python, regex

I need to find a timestamp pattern at the end of a string. For example, blahblahblah_tsYYYMMDDHHMMSS. I need to extract the time string and replace it with current timestamp. 
What is the regex for such pattern?

Comment: what is your approach or attempt?

Comment: Maybe google something like python regex? https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/python

Comment: `some_string.replace("YYYMMDDHHMMSS", my_current_timestamp_string)`?

Comment: I would use `split` with an underscore as a parameter, change the last element of the resulting list and `join` the list to get the target string. No regex needed here.

Comment: @Matthias That was my original approach. But I could mistakenly replace string that is not a timestamp. For example, I will replace filename_tsFNOWNOGEGE. Actually the requirement is to make sure the string ends with _ts plus 14 digits.

Comment: @rock321987 I was trying to use split string, but apparently it cannot guarantee the input string ends with the pattern I am looking for.

Comment: @Kevin this cheatsheet is very useful, thank you!

Comment: `\d{14}$` will suffice..https://regex101.com/r/xZ0hD3/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try making a function.

```
def tsExtractor(SomeString):        #your String
    LenSomeString = len(SomeString) #get length of String
    TargetString = SomeString[(LenSomeString - 14):LenSomeString] #Get placeholder of numeric data
    try:
        int(TargetString) #attempt to change to integer
    except ValueError:
        TargetString = 99998877665544  #not integer, put in some dummy data
    return str(TargetString) #change integer back to string
#examples
exampleString = 'blahblahblahyeahblahblahts20160616140003'
badString = 'Blahblahblahaldskfjlakdflaksdflkjasl500566'

exampleString = tsExtractor(exampleString)
print(exampleString)

exampleString = tsExtractor(badString)
print(exampleString)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @rock321987, i did this:

```
match = re.compile("_ts\d{14}$").match(pathstring)
if match:
    do something
```

It works pretty well.